# "Always running" console application

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I wrote a console application that is currently running on the server. It doesn't require any user input (other than parameters at start which can be done via start parameter).

Unfortunately this solution is bad, because someone can accidentally turn it off (i.e. when connecting to server using  Remote Desktop Connection and then logging off instead simply disconnecting). I need it to run all the time.

One solution would be to turn it into windows service, but so far using SC or third-party tools like nssm or RunAsService failed (SC and Nssm create a service but such service cannot be started).

I could completely rewrite my program to be a proper service... but to be honest I'm struggling with it (and from what I've read its not recommended practice).

Finally I could leave it as a console app and use task scheduler to run it -which does look like a decent solution, but (like I've mentioned) I need it to run all the time (it can be turned off and on - very short downtimes are not an issue).

Could I please ask for any help with setting such task?

SOLVED

After few attempts I've turned it into service using [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com) and[this great guide](http://www.ordina.nl/nl-nl/overige-content/2013/maart/building-windows-services-with-c-and-topshelf/).

Comment: What did you read that suggested that using a service is a bad idea? It seems like the perfect solution for you. Services can restart themselves on failure which is pretty useful.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the excellent TopShelf open source library for hosting your assembly as a service. It is pretty easy for creating a service that can install and uninstall itself, including options for the account to run under, etc.

Comment: Yeah, write it as a service. You're trying to reinvent the wheel here when there's no need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two methods you can use to run a .net program constantly in windows. Both have advantages and disadvantages.

**Windows Service**

- **Recommended Solution**
- Will startup service on computer start (doesn't require someone to log on)
- Has some (limited) error handling in the form of restarts
- Good for very reliable services that can run for long periods of time
- Service handles its own state
- Can easily crash due to memory leaks

**IIS Application Server**

- **Not recommended solution**
- Starts with windows, but might not start your application
- Requires newer windows to allow always on configuration
- Always on configuration is complicated
- State is handled by IIS
- Much better resiliency to crappy programming, as IIS will restart for you
- IIS will also likely kill your threads for you (so your scheduler will stop working)

I suspect the reason you were told that a windows service is not recommended was due to the fact that it could crash due to memory leaks. But that issue will occur no matter what, since your program needs to run for a long time (its not a problem with windows services, but long lived processes).

Comment: Services called daemon on Linux

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of rules that need to be followed to write a functional windows service including but not limited to

- the ability to complete the initialization process in a specific time
- a general understanding of threads

There is nothing inherently bad about writing a windows service they just require more effort and an installer.

Based on your description a scheduled job seems to fit your requirements

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to re-write your console app into a windows service and want it to be running all the time, the only solution I could see is:

- Create a small window's service, that checks to see if your *console process* is running or not.
- If it finds that there is no Console process, then start a new one.

  ```
  Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("YourConsoleApp.exe");
  if (pname.Length == 0)
     Process.Start("YourConsole.exe")
  else
      //Do nothing
  ```

Comment: I would strongly recommend against engineering a Rube Goldberg solution when there's a perfectly good, straightforward way of solving the exact same problem.

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, this might be a "bad" solution. However, you always have to write some anti-pattern before you come up with a proper design pattern for yourself. And sometimes, it might be necessary to adapt to _not so good_ solution just to avoid complication of a overly good design engineering solution which wasn't required in the first place.

Comment: It was initially my idea as well since I didn't really want to mess too much with the code, but indeed its not a good solution. So I'm +1 for thinking the same way as I did :P

Comment: If a windows service was created, no console app would be needed!